# 'inline' function definition for could not be written to module due to unrecognized expression or statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, c++-modules

I am experimenting with MSVC and modules.

I have the following code:

```
module;
#include "windows.h"
export module Module;
```

When I compile it in `Win32` configuration I get the following:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(1005,1): message : sorry: 'inline' function definition for 'ULONGLONG Int64ShllMod32(ULONGLONG,DWORD)' could not be written to module due to unrecognized expression or statement at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\winnt.h(1010,5)'.
1>If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
```

The same happens for functions `LONGLONG Int64ShraMod32(LONGLONG,DWORD)` and `ULONGLONG Int64ShrlMod32(ULONGLONG,DWORD)`.

The message does not show in `x64` configuration.

So I would like to know:

- Why the message comes out?
- If it is safe to suppress it, how can I suppress it?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5.0 (v143) and compiling with `/std:c++20`.

Comment: Why not provide a repro where they're asking to? These are three functions that use inline assembly, perhaps the 32-bit compiler cannot handle inline assembly in modules.

Comment: I did, but it was closed as duplicate by the feedback bot, giving me no clue on why it happens. Here is the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/inline-function-definition-for-could-n/10292803).

Comment: I looked inside file `ntdef.h`. There are `#ifdefs` that cause `Int64ShraMod32` to become just a macro. But in 32-bit builds, an inline function containing inline assembly gets compiled instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar accident to the problem you are having, so I am not sure if it will be helpful, but I will try to answer.

... In my case, it happened when I created the project using Visual Studio.
According to that, the compiler may recognize the header file as a target for compilation.
The proof is in the .vcproj included in the solution.

```
<ClCompile Include="srcfile.cpp" />
```

"srcfile.cpp" written in vcproj must contain only the source file.
If a header file is included here, the compiler will compile it and look for 'inline' functions. Therefore, the following example is NG.

```
<ClCompile Include="srcfile.h" />
```

The header file needs to be rewritten as below and included in the nearby  chunk.

```
<ClInclude Include="srcfile.h" />
```

My point may be wrong, or the problem in the title may be caused by another reason.
Also, I'm Japanese and don't understand English very well. sorry.